# Text and shape annotations

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there any way of adding text/shape annotations, like we can do in Cytoscape desktop? A workaround for this is create a node, and use it to create the annotation... But this does not seem the right solution.

Comment: It worked pretty well using nodes. The polygon shape allows you to create any type of shape. If you need text annotations, you can also create a node and put the text as label. The only downside is the need to filter out these fake nodes everytime when dealing with collections (they are fake nodes because they do not really belong to the graph - they are acting as annotations). Is there a simple fix to be able to create an element that is not a node or edge, but an annotation, for example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cytoscape.js is a library -- not a full-fledged app.  That means if you want app-level features like annotations, then you'll have to develop a feature on top of the library for that.

You could try using in-built things like nodes for this purpose, but you'd be better off creating an overlay div on top of the Cytoscape div in which you put your annotations.

If you want, you could organise your annotations feature as an extension so your code is more modular and reusable: http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions

I would encourage you to publish your extension if you decide to go that route.